# Undefined symbol in Boost.Python module

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-python

I'm trying to build a small Python extension for a certain instantiation of a templated library, using Boost.Python. This library uses extensively the CGAL library, which integrates fairly well with CMake, that I'm therefore using for my project.

Here's the code for my module (python_export.cpp):

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <CGAL/Exact_spherical_kernel_3.h>
#include "Sphere_intersecter.h" // header-only

typedef CGAL::Exact_spherical_kernel_3 SK;
template class Sphere_intersecter<SK>; // explicit for "-fno-implicit-templates"
typedef Sphere_intersecter<SK> SI;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(thickness_diag)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<SI>("SphereIntersecter", no_init)
        .def("add_sphere", &SI::add_sphere)
    ;
}
```

And the CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
project(ThicknessDiag-Python)

# CGAL
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)
include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})

# Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Shared library
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-implicit-templates")
set(ThicknessDiag-Python "thickness_diag")
add_library(${ThicknessDiag-Python} SHARED python_export.cpp)
set_target_properties(${ThicknessDiag-Python} PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
target_link_libraries(${ThicknessDiag-Python}
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES})
```

Detailed output of the compile command:

```bash
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/thickness_diag.dir/python_export.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -Dthickness_diag_EXPORTS -DCGAL_USE_MPFR -DCGAL_USE_GMP -frounding-math -fno-implicit-templates -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -isystem /usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o CMakeFiles/thickness_diag.dir/python_export.cpp.o -c /home/jmcomets/ThicknessDiag/tests/python_export.cpp
Linking CXX shared library thickness_diag.so
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -frounding-math -fno-implicit-templates -O3 -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,-soname,thickness_diag.so -o thickness_diag.so CMakeFiles/thickness_diag.dir/python_export.cpp.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmpfr -lgmp /usr/local/lib/libCGAL.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so -lpthread /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so -lpython2.7 /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so /usr/local/lib/libCGAL.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so -lpthread /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so -lpython2.7 /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

Output of importing the shared library:

```bash
$ python -c 'import thickness_diag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./thickness_diag.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python9converter6detail15registered_baseIRVK18Sphere_intersecterIN4CGAL18Spherical_kernel_3INS5_9CartesianINS5_4GmpqEEENS5_32Algebraic_kernel_for_spheres_2_3IS8_EEEEEE10convertersE
$ nm thickness_diag.so | grep _ZN5boost6python9converter6detail15registered_baseIRVK18Sphere_intersecterIN4CGAL18Spherical_kernel_3INS5_9CartesianINS5_4GmpqEEENS5_32Algebraic_kernel_for_spheres_2_3IS8_EEEEEE10convertersE
                 U _ZN5boost6python9converter6detail15registered_baseIRVK18Sphere_intersecterIN4CGAL18Spherical_kernel_3INS5_9CartesianINS5_4GmpqEEENS5_32Algebraic_kernel_for_spheres_2_3IS8_EEEEEE10convertersE
```

I've been struggling with this for the past two days, any help would be awesome ! :)

EDIT: output of ldd

```
$ ldd thickness_diag.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdfdff000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fd91eadf000)
    libCGAL.so.10 => /usr/local/lib/libCGAL.so.10 (0x00007fd91e8b4000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.55.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fd91e699000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd91e47c000)
    libboost_system.so.1.55.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fd91e278000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fd91dd79000)
    libboost_python.so.1.55.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fd91db2c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd91d829000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd91d612000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd91d253000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd91cf57000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd91cd4e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd91ef85000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd91cb37000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd91c933000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fd91c72f000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay I figured it out. Turns out that the option `-fno-implicit-templates` was preventing boost from doing its normal template instanciation (which is actually pretty obvious).

I then fell back on an error that I thought was fixed: `undefined symbol: _ZN18Sphere_intersecterIN4CGAL18Spherical_kernel_3INS0_9CartesianINS0_4GmpqEEENS0_32Algebraic_kernel_for_spheres_2_3IS3_EEEEEC1ERKS8_ (./thickness_diag.so)`

Which, when translated via [c++filt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt), gives: `Sphere_intersecter<...> >::Sphere_intersecter(Sphere_intersecter<...> const&)`

The copy-constructor, which wasn't implemented (non-copyable class)...

The solution was to remove the add the `boost::noncopyable` parameter to `boost::python::class_`:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <CGAL/Exact_spherical_kernel_3.h>
#include "Sphere_intersecter.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_spherical_kernel_3 SK;
template class Sphere_intersecter<SK>;
typedef Sphere_intersecter<SK> SI;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(thickness_diag)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<SI, boost::noncopyable>("SphereIntersecter")
        .def("add_sphere", &SI::add_sphere)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$man nm
...
"U" The symbol is undefined.
```

What does that mean? It's [not there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329722/nm-u-the-symbol-is-undefined).

Try `ldd` on your `so` . This will tell you all the libraries it uses. You then need to make sure all the libraries are on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I edited the question and added the output of ldd, I'm checking to see if all the libraries are there, but everything seems normal.

Comment: How do you set the path to pick these up?

Comment: I don't. That is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is at its default (empty). CMake adds `-L/usr/local/lib` and `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`, and all the libraries are in standard directories if I'm not mistaken.